# The SharePoint Migration Tool Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, migration, sharepointmigrationtool

I am trying to migrate my SharePoint 2013 site to Office 365. After providing valid credentials on both sides, when i select the site and press Next button, i face the below error. Unfortunately, there is not much details on this error.

[image]

> Sorry, you can’t create this site. Please enter a different Sharepoint
>   Online site URL or contact your administrator.

[image]

I tried different names but each time i get the same error.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you creating Site through tool? In order to migrate, I guess you need to create site manually and then paas it's URL to destination.

Comment: I tried both approaches. Created manually and tried with tool as well. In both cases i got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to keep in mind before migration

1- Check for your old SharePoint site or site collection features, customization's any third party solutions if installed in your SharePoint sites.

2- check the account has permission on SharePoint online and use same account

3- Make sure you use the right migration tool for migrating and this varies based on your SharePoint design structure and topology

4- Usually bringing changes in SharePoint online specially site collection level will take some time you should check after few minutes or more

5- Check the logs generated and fix the bugs which prevents migration

Comment: Setting the account as Site Collection Administrator on the SharePoint Online fixed the account. One must be using the same account on SharePoint online and On-Prem.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the SharePoint online site you enter exists.

We should enter the existing the SharePoint online site in the SharePoint migration tool.

Updated：

You check if the first sign-in account has the permission on the SharePoint online site.

Comment: Yes i tried this too. I created site manually and passed the URL, however it gave the same error.

Comment: Check if you can access the SharePoint online site in browser.

Comment: Yes that is accessible. I can see the content, pages etc.

Comment: uninstall and re-install the sharepoint migration tool

Comment: Just did that today. Also i tried giving full permissions to my SharePoint 2013 account on Office 365, same results. Still getting the same error.

Comment: BTW, the error has been changed... although i have provided Full Control on the site...see here... https://imgur.com/B2MBFwh

Comment: check if the first sign-in account has the permission on the SharePoint online site

Comment: Thanks Amy for your thoughts. I actually made the same account as Site Collection Admin on the SP Online site and that solved the issue. Previously it just had full controls on the root site. My first migration is successful, however, when i tried to access the SPO site, it gave me Access Denied error. While the account i am using has permissions on both SP2013 and SPO sites. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think i need to learn how to keep patience. After few minutes, the Access Denied error went away and the site was accessible. May be SP Online is doing some kind of checks on its side for data verification. Thank you very much for staying with me.

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could accept the reply as answer.

Comment: I beg to differ that, your original answer did not solve the problem so i am afraid that will not be useful  and unfortunately i cannot mark it as answer for now. Can you please Edit and update it according to the solution that worked for me? Then i'll be more than happy to mark it as answer. Cheers

Comment: I have updated the reply.

Comment: Done. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, is just a little mistake. Please ensure your URL is valid
just like

https://sample.sharepoint.com\sites\test  <--- not correct

https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/test  <--- not correct